# Flex 4 display selected item from spark DropDownList

Tags: apache-flex

My stakeholder has a request to display the currently selected item from the DropDownList control(s) in the application. For example totalscreen that drop down with [1, 2, 3, 4] if 
3 is selected then the only items in localscreen drop down will be [1, 2,3] and if the 2 is selected,for the nextworkscreen will only have [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2KU6.png) is display. I am using the dropdownlist and ArrayCollection.

[image]

Any thoughts on if this is possible and if so how to implement it would really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Using Flash Builder 4.7 with Apache Flex 4.11 sdk

Answer (score 0):

Set the dataProvider for Local screen to an array with the appropriate values in a change event handler for Total screens.  Same goes for Network screens (set its dataprovider when Local screens changes).

The API docs have an example of using a change event:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DropDownList.html

(see change="updateSelection(event)" in the example mxml)

Comment: i'm newbie to flex its what u mean ?                       private function updateLocal(event:IndexChangeEvent):void
   {
    var aLocal:Array = [];
    var idx:uint;
    var length:uint = totalscreenSelect.selectedItem.data;
    for(idx=0; idx<length; idx++)
    {
     aLocal.push({data:"label"+idx});
    }
    
   }                                                 <s:DropDownList id="totalscreen" dataProvider="{_dataProviders}" change="updateLocal(event);"/>        but there are error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

```
            private function updateLocal(event:Event):void
        {
            //var aLocalScreen:Object;
            var idx:uint;
            var length:uint = totalscreenSelect.selectedItem.data;
            aLocal= new ArrayCollection();

            for(idx=0; idx<length; idx++)
            {
                //Alert.show("An event occurred.");
                var data:Object = new Object();
                data["label"]=idx+1;
                data["data"] = idx+1;
                aLocal.addItem(data);
            }
        }
```